# Algorithm to convert expression tree to polynomial form

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, expression-trees, polynomials

I tried to search using different keywords, but didn't find anything helpful. I'm not even sure that "Polynomial" is the right term here, please advise.

I'm trying to find Recursive Algorithm (Ideally on C#) to CONVERT/EXPAND my expression tree to simplified standard (polynomial, I guess) form. For example:

**Input:**

> (X1+X2+X3*X4)*X5+X6

**Output:**

> X1*X5 + X2*X5 + X3*X4*X5 + X6

I have set of source classes:

```
public abstract class Expr
{ 
    public static Op Op(string operatorName, params Expr[] children)
    {
        var res = new Op() { Operator = operatorName };
        res.Children.AddRange(children);
        return res;
    }
    public static Var Var(string valName)
    {
        var res = new Var(){ Name = valName};
        return res;
    }
}
public class Op:Expr
{
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public List<Expr> Children = new List<Expr>();
}

public class Var:Expr
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to implement the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Var>> SimplifyToPolynom(Expr expression)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

//USE CASE:
public static void Test()
{
    //(X1+X2+X3*X4)*X5+X6
    var inputExpression =
        Expr.Op("+",
            Expr.Op("*"
                , Expr.Op("+"
                    , Expr.Var("X1")
                    , Expr.Var("X2")
                    , Expr.Op("*"
                        , Expr.Var("X3")
                        , Expr.Var("X4")
                            )
                          )
                , Expr.Var("X5")
                    )
            , Expr.Var("X6")
        );

    var output = SimplifyToPolynom(inputExpression);
    // Exected result [[X1,X5],[X2,X5], [X3,X4,X5], [X6]]
}
```

Comment: Are + and * the only possible operators?

Comment: For my task yes, but of  course it'd be great if solution can be scaled to more

Answer (score 0):

Go through the tree.

Whenever you find a "*" node that contains a "+" node replace that sub-tree with the expanded form.

You take the list of children of the "+" node and replace the "*" node with a new "+" where each child is a "*" between all other children of the original "*" node and one of the children of the "+" node.

Since whenever you expand you push the "*" node down the tree it will eventually finish since your tree is finite.

You can extend the algorithm to pick up any other similar expansion you would like.